# jQuery binding after .load and .getScript only works after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getscript

Here is one for you jQuery Ajax wizards. Using jQuery 1.7.2 but also tried 1.5.1...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The main page loads an external (same domain) JS file. In the call back from the click event I do an AJAX call to login by posting the login form. Based on the parameters passed back (JSON) from the authentication call I do a .load of a some content and a navigation bar into the main document.

```
    $("#loginForm_submit").click(function() {
    var action = $("#loginForm").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        sbgusername: $("#sbgusername").val(),
        sbpassword: $("#sbpassword").val()
    };              

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(loginData){
            if(loginData.success == true){ 
                // this will be moved into a loop to laod multiple apps into one page. For testing
                // all arrays only have value
                var webapps = loginData.webapps; //array
                var webappservers = loginData.webappservers; //array 
                var webappscripts = loginData.webappscripts; //array
                var webAppContent = webappservers[0] + '  #' + webapps[0] + 'Content'; 
                // webAppContent = 'api/wpapp.cfm #wpContent';
                var webAppNav = webappservers[0] + '  #' + webapps[0] + 'Nav';
                // webAppNav = 'api/wpapp.cfm #wpNav';
                var scriptURL = webappscripts[0];
                // scriptURL = 'api/wpBase.js';
                var scriptLoad = webapps[0] + 'Load'; 
                // scriptLoad = 'wpLoad';
                $("#sbcore").load(webAppContent); //sbcore is div in main document
                $("#nav").load(webAppNav); //nav is div in main document
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false },{async:false});
                $.getScript(scriptURL, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                   window[scriptLoad](); //because getScript loads methods into global context from what I can tell
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false },{async:true});
            }
            else
            {   alert(loginData.message);
                }
        },
        error: function(errorData){
            alert("Server couldn't be reached. Please Try again.");
        }

    });
    return false;               

});
```

The navbar loaded looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li id="nw-menu-dashboard" class="first"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a id="nw-menu-privatearticles" href="#" accesskey="2" title="">Articles</a></li>
</ul>
```

The JS loaded by scriptLoad as scriptURL is this (note it is loaded from the same domain):

```
    function nwLoad() {
    //alert("nwBase.js ran");
    nwLoadMenu();
}
function nwLoadMenu() {
      //alert("here");
      $("#nw-menu-dashboard").on("click",function() { 
          //e.preventDefault();
          alert("doDashboard");
      });   
      $("#nw-menu-privatearticles").on("click",function() { 
          //e.preventDefault();
          alert("doPrivateArticles");
      });
}
```

So this is the weird thing, if I uncomment the `//alert("nwBase.js ran");`  or the `//alert("here");` in the immediately above then the menus are bound to the divs and the menu click alerts work as desired. But as above with out the alerts before the bindings it doesn't work. I've tried binding using .click, .live, .

I've tried loading synchronous, waiting etc. and can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you implement waiting? Via `setTimeout` or via a callback? The callback should have worked..

Comment: Waiting as in not doing anything for a minute. I would have thought that was the same as a setTimeout but just realized that maybe the binds didn't have anything to find to when they were loaded. I added a setTimeout which didn't work. As for using a callback I'm not clear how I would implement one for this situation. The original call for the getScript is already in a callback. I also tried putting the ajax:synchronous around the content and nav loads as well as getScript and still no luck. I'm not super skilled at jQuery/JS so any tips on code would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Robin Maben, you put me on the right track. I linked the the call backs from the different loads and it works as expected. Please post your suggestion as an answer so I can give you credit with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you re-try the waiting bit via a callback (instead of via `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

It is not wired, that after you uncomment the `alert` function everything is like you need.
Because in that time until you didn't push the OK button your menu has loaded and your CLICK function binds correct.
call your `nwLoadMenu` function when a response will come - use callback function or deffered object!